# dual boot problems, grub 2 fails to install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a laptop with a pre installed Windows 8. It uses UEFI firmware. I tried to install Ubuntu 12 alongside Windows 8 and got an error:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target.
The installed system will not boot.
```

Any idea on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

- Try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an emergency disc. This might fix the problem, but there's a chance that it won't. If it doesn't work, save the URL that Boot Repair provides. If the next suggestion also doesn't work, post the URL that Boot Repair gave you, along with any additional observations. The URL will point to a document with partitioning and other configuration details for your computer, which will be helpful in doing further diagnosis of your problem.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a suitable medium. Try booting with it. If rEFInd lets you boot both Windows and Linux, install the Debian package version of the program from Ubuntu. This will then take over from GRUB 2 as the default boot manager. (It's essentially maintenance-free, unless something else gets in the way or you have a problem with a kernel bug or the like.)

Comment: I am not able to get into ubuntu at all.. boot repair failed as it was unable to boot in efi. ill try rEFInd and tell you about it